# WordPress Search inside all Taxonomy and Terms of a Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm trying to do a Search in WordPress. What this search must do:

1. Get all taxonomy content.

Example: I have a Custom Post Type (CPT) called **Houses**, this CPT have 10 taxonomies, they are: FRONT COLOR, FLOOR, ROOF...

I need to get all content of these taxonomy in that search.

So, if user search for "**white**", it must get all titles of those taxonomy that contain "**white**" in the title.

The problem I'm facing is: I made all this code but its not reading taxonomy content.

```
search = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'oficinas',
        's' => $searchfor
    )
);
if ($search->found_posts>0) {
    foreach ($search->posts as $post) {
        setup_postdata($post);
        include 'modulos/box-ch-oficinas.php';
    }
}else{
    echo '<div class="box-resultado"><h2>Nenhuma oficina encontrada!</h2></div>';
}
```

**Current Output = nothing**

---

I hope someone will help me or maybe give me a way to do that. I'm beginning in WordPress but I have a huge PHP skills.

Comment: What is the current output you are getting?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Output = nothing.

Comment: Can you please provide more details. Have you debug the code? Is `$search->found_posts>0` working? Debug line by line and you'll find a specific point that you're facing the exact problem. Mention it

Comment: I already debug. I guess the problem is: its not going inside taxonomy but i dont know how to do a search inside all of them

Comment: This question may help you : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33640/how-do-i-search-inside-specific-taxonomies-in-wordpress

Comment: I tried something like this @Ramesh but it just read 1 taxonomy, I need a way to read all of them